# does software requiring newer version of glibc = Operating System update?

Tags: upgrade, glibc

I am trying to test a newer version of a software package and get this error message when trying to launch

```
Error: unsupported version of GNU C Library (glibc)
       minimum supported version : 2.12
       installed version:        : 2.11
```

In scenarios such as this

- does this mean in practical terms that I need to upgrade the OS?  I am running SLES 11.4 having glibc 2.11; and SLES 12.3 is the latest currently available,
- Is there a safe way to update glibc for a given enterprise type of OS such as SLES, or RHEL?  Or is that asking for major problems, and is updating glibc something that should not be done manually on a *production* type of server running expensive licensed software packages?

Comment: »»Is there a safe way to update glibc«« : Usually not. But you can install a hidden glibc ( like `/opt/glibc212/lib/` ) and point to 2.12 when you run the application.

Comment: tried to use glibc-2.12.2, built from source .tar.gz using `--prefix=/usr/local/glibc-2.12.2` then doing `setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/glibc-2.12.2/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}` before running software... instead of the clean Error message that is printed which is after a GUI popup I now get `segmentation fault (core dumped)` immediately at the prompt with no GUI popup.  giving up.